# Can I use Unity to edit a prefab created in Blender?

Tags: unity, blender, rigging

I've imported a character from Blender. The character is made of metaballs and so doesn't import properly. I'm trying to edit the character within Unity using the rig from the original Blender object.

The problem I'm running into is that I can only access the bones when the object is instantiated. The rig/armature object doesn't unfold in the project resource folder, and double clicking on the top-level object just opens it in Blender. So I can't seem to make edits that can later be instantiated.

Is there a way to use Unity to edit a prefab made in Blender so it can be instantiated? Any other suggestions welcome.

Screenshots for reference:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I just had to drag the edited prefab instance from the hierarchy pane to the project pane, creating another prefab that kept my edit.

In case it's helpful for anyone, this is the resource that helped me get my head around how prefabs work. https://unity.com/prefabs

Answer (score 1):

[Quick Edit Unity Plugin](https://youtu.be/P8pcRkF8VJg)
Yes, you can. You have to write your own custom script to do this, or download one (such as the plugin linked above).

However, usually someone would want to do this to modify models at runtime. Odds are you will be better off building your models in a way that works for unity.

But yes, via scripting you can tweak any asset you want... the catch is you have to either make or find a script to do it.

Comment: Thanks for this. My issue was a bit more basic, though. I edited the question to make it clearer now that I have my head around the issue.